# VBA: How to replace entire Excel cell value basing on its content?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I have an Excel Spreadsheet with some names in a cells. There can be as one name per cell as multiple names in one cell.

For example: Cell A5 contains "Joe", cell BD54 contains "Joe;Harry;Molly", cell YY1 contains "Harry;Butch".

What I wan to achieve is to replace values of all cells that contains "Joe" or "Molly" with "1, regardless of what else is in this cells, and celss that contains just "Harry" or "Butch" will be replaced with "0" if it does not contain "Joe" or "Molly". For example above, result should be as follows: A5 conains "1", BD54 contains "1", YY1 contains "0".

I'm a total newbie in VBA - would you, gents, please assis with that? I suspect that Cells.Replace should be used here, however, I'm not sure how to pass a list of names to it

```
Dim Findtext As String
 Dim Replacetext As String
 Findtext = "Joe","Molly"
 Replacetext = "1"
 Findtext = "Harry","Butch"
 Replacetext = "0"
 Cells.Replace What:=Findtext, Replacement:=Replacetext, LookAt:=xlPart, _
 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
 ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: Welcome to SU! What have you already achieved, it would be nice to take a look at your result?

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted. This question shows effort to solve and an indication as to where OP is stuck. Maybe the language isn't crystal clear, but it's still a good effort.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but instead you can do something like this, using [instr](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/funcao-instr-HA001228857.aspx) -

```
Sub test()
Dim check1 As Integer
Dim check2 As Integer
Dim find1 As String
find1 = "a"
Dim find2 As String
find2 = "b"
For Each c In Range("A:A")
    check1 = InStr(1, c, find1, 1)
    check2 = InStr(1, c, find2, 1)
        If check1 > 0 Then
            c.Value = 1
        End If
        If check2 > 0 Then
            c.Value = 2
        End If
Next

End Sub
```

Basically, it looks in the cell for the position of the search string. If it doesn't find it, it reverts to `0`. So if it does find it, the check1 or check2 integers will be >0. If it find both strings, it will revert to the second (or last) `if` integer.

Comment: So if I have 15 names of "Joe" type and 15 names of "Harry" type, I will need to use smth like
`
Dim find1 As String
find1 = "a"
Dim find2 As String
find2 = "b"
...
Dim find30 As String
find30 = "Z"
`

Comment: dim find1 as string _ find1 = "Joe" @Volkodav2003 - or just use the string in the instr() in place of the string variable

Comment: I need to be careful with "Return" key on this site... So if I have 30 names I should do 30 comparisons? Or I can simplify this somehow keeping in mind that this 30 names can be divided into 2 groups?

Some pseudocode as I not found yet how to implement this:
`"Joe", "Mary", "Jim" BelongsTo "MyTeam" group;
"Harry", "Butch","Jake" BelongsTo "OtherTeam" group;
Check CellValue;
If CellValue Contains MyTeamGroupMember string, then replace CellValue with 1;
Next;
If CellValue Contains OtherTeamGroupMember string, then replace CellValue with 0`

Comment: @Volkodav2003 no, `instr` only works with one string, not multiple. one `instr` per comparison

Comment: So pity. Well, I'll try and let you know, how it works

Comment: Fail. Tried with 2 strings added instead of `Find1` and `Find2` in your script. After runnin macros, nothing has been changed.

Comment: @Volkodav2003 it works. Make sure you changed all the values and ranges to match your data.

Answer (score 0):

to make things a little more generic... you could have the list of search names to replace somewhere on your sheet. You'd get each of the ranges for replacing with One and Zero respectively, then loop through the (selected) target range, making the replacements.

I had data like this:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DirtyHarry()

Dim target_range As Range
Dim search_names_range As Range

'select the range you want to do the replace on before you start!
Set target_range = Selection

'do the ones first
Set search_names_range = Sheet1.Range("E2:E" & Sheet1.Range("E2").End(xlDown).Row)
BinaryReplaceBleepBloop search_names_range, target_range, 1

'now do the zeroes
Set search_names_range = Sheet1.Range("G2:G" & Sheet1.Range("G2").End(xlDown).Row)
BinaryReplaceBleepBloop search_names_range, target_range, 0

End Sub



Private Function BinaryReplaceBleepBloop(search_names As Range, target_range As Range, replacement_value As Integer)

Dim search_string_cell As Object
Dim target_cell As Object
Dim this_name As String

Debug.Print "Searching " & target_range.AddressLocal & " for the names in " & search_names.AddressLocal & " to replace with " & replacement_value

'loop through each of the search names
For Each search_string_cell In search_names.Cells

    this_name = search_string_cell.Value

    Debug.Print "..." & this_name

    'loop through each of the cells in the selected target range
    For Each target_cell In target_range.Cells

        Debug.Print "......target_cell value is " & target_cell.Value

        If InStr(1, target_cell.Value, this_name) > 0 Then

            Debug.Print "......Found it! Replacing " & target_cell.Value & " with " & replacement_value

            target_cell.Value = replacement_value

        Else

            Debug.Print "......Didn't find it. Nothing to see here."

        End If

    Next target_cell

Next search_string_cell

End Function
```

The output in the Immediate window looked like this when I ran it:
[image]